I need an intuitive explanation of Number of Normals to a conicoid
I've recently started learning analytic geometry. I'm quite confused as to how a conicoid can have multiple normals to it from a given point. I've gone through the algebra and the derivation of the equations. But I can quite put my head around, the geometric meaning of it. So it'd be of great help if someone could explain it with the help of a few diagrams.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

No smooth surface can have multiple normals at a single point. You can only have multiple normals if the surface has an abrupt change in orientation, such as along an edge of a polyhedron, where each of the meeting planar faces has its own normal. Even then, we don't normally think of the surface as having "two normals" along the edge, but instead consider it to not have a normal at all. But that should not apply to a conicoid anyway. What makes you think there should be multiple normals?

Perhaps you are dealing with a self-intersecting surface, like Plücker's conoid? Along the intersection, the two intersecting sub-surfaces will each have its own normal.
